# Assigning Tasks based on fields status

Tags: workflow, tasks

I want to send a task based on these few things all on Opportunities Object:

1) Port Status must equal 'Rejected or Completed'

THEN

Send a task to whoever the 'Assigned Service Coordinator' is to review this opportunity. This Assigned Service Coordinator is a custom field lookup relationship to Users

I tried a WF to trigger once Port Status is changed to Rejected or Completed but when creating the Action on the WF, I can only send a task to a specific user each time or group of users.

Comment: If WF is insufficient, try Process Builder instead.

Comment: Process builder is definitly the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Use Process Builder as of Spring '15.

Comment: Same as the other one, can you add some more info? :)